# Can my Sims with music skills perform at venues with Showtime?

Tags: the-sims-3

If I have a Sim with a high guitar skill or drums skill, can I get them to perform at a SimFest or a venue or something? Can I use these Sims to do any of the new Showtime features?

Comment: I would think so, but I don't have Showtime, so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If the lot has an instrument there, there should be no reason why not. Some NPC sims might even tip you if you're good enough ;)